# Searching only on current domain but NOT in sub-domain

Tags: search, coldfusion, ldap, dns

I am trying to search for all users in a domain A but I do not wish for the search to dig into the sub-domain B.

How can this be done?

I tried including this into filter but not working:

```
(!(distinguishedName=*DC=domainA*))
```

I am using coldfusion LDAP function.

Comment: What is a sub-domain? Do you mean that you wish to search for entries that are subordinate to one entry, but excluding some of the entries that subordinate?

Comment: We have 2 domains. for example: Domain A is DC=domainA, DC=com and Domain B is DC=domainB, DC=domainA, DC=com. If you look at it as a tree, it is a sub-domain. What I wish is the search to only search in Domain A but never in Domain B but because they are somewhat linked, the search function is searching through Domain B as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you can accomplish what you are describing by using start and scope, rather than filter:

```
<cfldap start="dc=primaryDomain,dc=com" scope="base" .....>
```

See [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_03.html)

*edit*

Alternatively, you could first get all users through the whole directory, then filter it further with a Query of Query call.

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="filteredLDAP">
SELECT * FROM ldapResults WHERE dn not LIKE '%domainA%'
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried that but I am not getting ANY results back at all but the object I'm looking for is definitely there. So I was quite puzzled by this and have taken different approach

Comment: I guess the reason why it doesn't return is because I'm looking for someone like this: cn=meee,ou=Cool,ou=awesome,dc=domainA,dc=com

Comment: Yeah, that's going to be a problem with the example I provided.  I'll update my answer with another option.

Comment: Excellent! I have tried it and it worked nicely! Thanks so much :)